# How to prove that these sequences converge / diverge

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

1)$$\lim_{n\to \infty}10 - \sqrt{n} = -\infty $$

I know that I have to find the function $N(M)$ such that $$10 - \sqrt{n} > M$$ but I'm unsure of what function to compare $$10 - \sqrt{n}  $$ to.

2)$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n - 2\sqrt{n}= \infty $$

I know this is somewhat similar to problem 1) except with $-M$.

3)$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{5n^2 +2n}{n^2 - 3} = 5$$

I know that you have to set

$$\lvert \frac{5n^2 +2n}{n^2 - 3} - 5 \rvert < M $$

and find a function for $N(M)$.

For my function $N(M)$ i got $$\max \{2, 3m + 15, 3+\frac{17} m \}$$ but I'm unsure.

Please help!

Comment: do you know the $\epsilon$-N definition of a limit for a sequence?

Comment: In the first line, in the limit definition, I presume you mean $n$ instead of $x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We have for any $M>0$

$$\left|10-\sqrt{n}\right|>M$$

whenever $n>N(M)=\max\left(100,(M+10)^2\right)$.

Comment: why wouldn't N(M) be $$(10-m)^2$$

Comment: @RyanT.Donnelly For any $M>0$, if we take initially $N\ge 100$, then for $n>N$, $|10-\sqrt{n}|=\sqrt{n}-10>M\implies n>(M+10)^2$.  Therefore, whenever, $n>\max(100,(M+10)^2)$, we have $|10-\sqrt{n})|>M\implies 10-\sqrt{n}<-M$.